Congruence lattice of a semiring
A famous result of Funayama and Nakayama states that the congruence lattice of any lattice is a distributive lattice [1]. Also, it can be proved that the lattice is a frame/ complete Heyting algebra 2. For proof, see Chapter VI, Theorem 9 of Birkhoff or Chapter 8, Theorem 8.1 of Blyth.
To make my question self-contained, let me define everything.

A congruence $\rho$ on an algebraic structure $S$ is an equivalence relation on $S$ that is also a subalgebra of $S\times S$. That is, $\rho$ is compatible with the binary operations on $S$.


To understand the join and meet of two congruences on an algebraic structure $S$, it is enough to understand join and meet of two equivalence relations.


My question is concerning the congruence lattice of semirings.

Is the congruence lattice of a semiring again a complete Heyting algebra?

I have tried to modify the proof given in 3 and 4. It is easy to show that Cong(S), the congruence lattice of a semiring, is a complete lattice.
I need to show that if $(a,b)\in \theta\wedge \bigvee_{i\in I} \theta_i \implies (a,b)\in \bigvee_{i\in I} (\theta\wedge \theta_i)$.
[1]:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_lattice_problem#:~:text=Theorem%20(Funayama%20and%20Nakayama%201942,of%20any%20lattice%20is%20distributive.&text=%2C%20as%20a%20rule%2C%20for%20submodules,Dilworth%20proved%20the%20following%20result.

Every ring is a semiring. Not every ring is congruence-distributive (see, for example, this question). Hence, not every semiring is congruence-distributive.

Hey @amrsa, thank you. I found this statement in Golan's book [https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-94-015-9333-5], See chapter 8. He claimed that the result is true.
It now seems to be a mistake in his book.

It's difficult to check because what I can see in the beginning of the chapter (the part I have access to) is "Indeed, by an easy modification of a result Funayama and Nakayama, $Con(R)$ is in fact a frame and hence a semiring. See [Birkhoff,1973] for details." I don't have access to that book, although I have to the 1967 version. Yet, I don't know where to look for in that book. But I think my comment above is clear enough (and you seem to agree).

I posted an answer in order to close this subject. I did so with a community wiki answer because you already had your answer from the comments.

A ring doesn't have to be congruence-distributive.
For example, $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$ has $M_3$, the least modular non-distributive lattice as its congruence lattice.
Now, if you have an algebra $\mathbf A = (A,F)$, where $F$ is the set of operations of that algebra, and $F' \subseteq F$, then, with $\mathbf A' = (A,F')$, we have $Con(\mathbf A) \leq Con(\mathbf A')$, that is, the lattice of congruences of $\mathbf A$ is a sub-lattice of the lattice of congruences of $\mathbf A'$.
Concerning rings ans semirings, these differ in which semirings lack the additive inverse operation, $-$ (here, as an unary operation), and so, if $\mathbf R$ is a ring and $\mathbf R'$ is the semiring that results from that ring by dropping the $-$ operation (in Universal Algebra we say that $\mathbf R'$ is an algebraic reduct of $\mathbf R$), then $Con(\mathbf R) \leq Con(\mathbf R')$.
So whatever algebraic reduct $\mathbf S$ we may consider of $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$, for example, its semiring reduct, it will be such that the non-distributive lattice $M_3$ is a sub-lattice of $Con(\mathbf S)$.
(And for many more counter-examples, you just have to find rings which are not congruence-distributive.)

Please provide a reference for $Con(A)\leq Con(A')$. It would be very helpful. Thanks for this intuitive answer.

I can see that the inclusion is true for a semiring.

I can't find a reference, but it's kind of obvious. A congruence on $\mathbf A$ is also a congruence on $\mathbf A'$ since $\mathbf A$ has all the operations that $\mathbf A$ has, and perhaps some more. That gives us containment, that is, $Con(\mathbf A)\subseteq Con(\mathbf A')$. The meet and join of each pair of operations in $Con(\mathbf A)$ is the same as computed in $Con(\mathbf A')$ since both coincide with the ones computed in the set of all equivalence relations on $A$.
